# My firestore sucurity rule for getting multiple documents doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have this rule

```
allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.author
```

and it doesn't allow me to get multiple documents with getDocs.

But it allows to get a document with getDoc.

PS: I used this to retrieve the documents

```
const col = collection(db, collectionPath)
const documents = await getDocs(col)
```

and got this error

> FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

but this worked

```
const col = collection(db, collectionPath)
const document = await getDoc(doc(col,documentID))
```

Comment: Can you update your question by sharing the query you are trying to retrieve documents?

Comment: @RoopaM I just added the query as you requested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're [confusing security rules with filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters). The security rule in your question will only let through queries where all documents satisfy the rule, so if you try to get the entire collection using `getDocs(collection)`, it won't return anything.

Instead, try querying your database using your Author field, like the method in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60826445#60827144), which uses `whereEqualTo()` to filter results by field:

```
const col = firestore.collection(db, collectionPath).whereEqualTo("author", author)
const documents = await getDocs(col)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, my problem has been solved!